# selecting data from 2 tables where multiple columns and rows intersect with 'X'

Tags: mysql

its tricky to explain what i am trying to do so here goes
I have 2 tables derived from a single excel spreadsheet. the spreadsheet defines causes and effects.It has 3 points of reference so i cant make it into 1 table

this spreadsheet has a list of events down the left and effects accross the top. these are associated with each other by inserting an X in the row/column matching the event to the effect. So the intersecting columns/rows form a matrix. So for eg an event could be. 'turn on lightswitch'. follow this row along untill 'X' is found. then follow column up to effects and it shows 'light turns on' (its a little more complicated than that in reality) there can be multiple effects defined by X's in the same row

My idea was in the where statement to use table1.* and table2.* but I was looking for a wildcard to search rows/columns but after research this is not possible in mysql. Using OR for all the furter row/column combinations wont work because it just shows everything with an X in

I am a bit stumped how to query the X row/column part of the table so only the 'example' result part of the query is displayed after searching all the X's A single query below is successful but i need to search table1.1-60 table2.2-61 for occurrances of 'X' by only changeing the '%example%' part of the query in a webpage mysql/php type form and then displaying the results on another page

any suggestions/alternatives welcome thanks

```
SELECT
table1.equipment,
table1.tagno,
table2.equipment,
table2.action,
table2.service,
table2.tagno
FROM
table1 ,
table2
WHERE
table1.tagno LIKE '%example%' AND
table1.1 = 'X' AND
table2.2 = 'X'
```

Comment: Is it an option to re-model the data?  I would consider having separate tables for events and effects with a join table to describe where the X's should be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no natural way to join column `N` from `table1` with column `N+1` in `table2`; you'll have to specify the joins "by hand" (or in a program, both of which will be ugly).

You want:

```
select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.tagno like '%example%' AND t1.1 ='X' and t2.2 = 'X'
UNION
select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.tagno like '%example%' AND t1.2 ='X' and t2.3 = 'X'
UNION
-- ...
```

This could be very inefficient. As suggested in the comments, remodelling the data would give you cleaner queries and a happier future.

Comment: i have no problem remoddeling the data. so you mean strip the 60x61 matrix off both tables into its own table. would this be the join table you mean

Answer (score 0):

To give more insight into my suggestion, I would re-model the data like so:

```
CREATE TABLE effects (
         id INT,
         name VARCHAR(100)
       );

CREATE TABLE events (
         id INT,
         name VARCHAR(100)
       );

CREATE TABLE effects_events (
         effect_id INT,
         event_id INT
       );
```

effects_events is a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

So you could query it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE events.id = effects_events.event_id AND effects_events.effect_id = effects.id AND effects.name = 'light turns on';
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM effects WHERE effects.id = effects_events.effect_id AND effects_events.event_id = events.id AND events.name = 'turn on lightswitch';
```

I might be misunderstanding something in your question but this seems like the most straightforward solution to me.